# Parallelogram Theorem question

Tags: geometry

[image]

I'm having a hard time picturing why $\alpha$ is the same at the two angles shown in the picture. I know it has something to do with the parallelogram theorem. Could someone help me see it?

Thank you!

Comment: Not sure which in angles in the picture you are referring to. Please edit the question to include an adequate description of the problem in words. Also, could you define $R$, $R_h$ and $R_v$?

Comment: I'm not sure about whether $R$ is orthogonal on the left side of the parallelogram.

Answer (score 0):

Let's give the name "L" to the diagonal line at the right-hand end of the figure. I'm assuming that R and L are perpendicular. Imagine them being rigidly connected to each other to make a "T" shape. Now rotate this "T" shape in a clockwise direction. Hold up your fingers in this T shape, if it helps. When R gets to be vertical, L will be horizontal. So, in their original positions, the angle betwwen R and the vertical must have been the same as the angle between L and the horizontal. In other words, the two angles marked "$\alpha$" must be equal.

This isn't a proof, but it should help you see why the two "$\alpha$" angles are the same.

It will probably be easier to see if you draw a diagram where "$\alpha$" is quite a small angle -- say around 15 or 20 degrees. In the current diagram, it's around 45 degrees, which causes confusion.

Comment: Hi bubba. Thanks for the reply. Yes, R and L are perpendicular. I still am having trouble trying to picture it geometrically. Why would rotating the "T" shape 20 degrees lead to the angle between R and Rv to be 20 degrees as well?

Comment: Well, L and R are locked together. So, as L rotates away from horizontal, R must rotate away from vertical **by the same amount**. Make a T-shaped piece of cardboard and play with it.